# OpenVINO demos: multichannel-face-detection demo; TBB LINK 2019 error

Tags: c++, multithreading, computer-vision, tbb, openvino

I'm trying to tune the multichannel-face-detection demo of the OpenVINO library, but when I try to use TBB for parallel processing, the IDE give me this error:

```
error LINK 21019: reference to external symbol "private: void __cdecl TbbArenaWrapper::init(void)" (?init@TbbArenaWrapper@@AEAAXXZ) "  not solved in the function "public: __cdecl TbbArenaWrapper::TbbArenaWrapper<>(void)" (??$?0$$V@TbbArenaWrapper@@QEAA@XZ)"
```

I correctly linked the libraries, tbb_debug.lib and put the dll in the output directory.

Anyone has some advices?

Thank's.

Comment: Do you use the OpenVINO library from official package or have you built it by your own?

Comment: Hi, I'm working with the OpenVINO official package pre-built library. So I've download the tbb library and built it by my own but the visual studio 2017 compiler give me always the same error.

Comment: Is this critical for you to tbb built on your own? OpenVINO is released with tbb libraries and headers. On my machine, the header located inside C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino_2019.3.379\inference_engine\external\tbb, the dll libraries - C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\openvino_2019.3.379\inference_engine\bin\intel64\Release I guess that error, you got, because OpenVINO is built against another, incompatible with yours, version of TBB library.

Comment: So I suppose that the mistake could be the built version of tbb lib. Because I face this problem only when working with openvino samples and library.

Comment: If you want to use your tbb build: another option would be re-build OpenVINO from sources (you can find repo on github) using your tbb build. But, from my point of view, it would be easier just re-use tbb from OpenVINO package.

Comment: This symbol is not from tbb.dll, and TbbArenaWrapper is not a TBB class. I would guess you need to link with some special OpenVINO library.

Comment: Is the issue resolved? I think it is worth to add an answer if so

Comment: The issue is not resolved, for my project I've used the standard thread and future library of c++

Comment: I've solved the issue building and using the tbb intel librearies with openvino and opencv separately.